# How to swap values from two fields at the same time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the data in one column.
Ex:

dog
dog
cat
fox

How do I change the value of all dogs to fox and values of all fox to dog at the same time?  If I run an UPDATE SET it will change all dogs to fox, then I run the second one it'll turn everything into dogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update
    table
set
    animal = case anmial when 'dog' then 'fox' else 'dog' end
where
    animal in ('dog', 'fox')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than just dogs and foxes you could consider making a conversion table to help you with the update. That way you won't need a case statement.

```
declare @original table
( 
  pk int identity(1,1),
  column1 varchar(max) 
)

insert into @original 
select 'fox' 
union all 
select 'dog'

declare @conversion table 
( 
  valueFrom varchar(max)
 ,valueTo varchar(max) 
)

insert into @conversion 
select 'fox','dog' 
union all 
select 'dog','fox'

select * from @original

update original
set original.column1 = c.valueTo
from @original as original inner join @conversion as c
on original.column1 = c.valueFrom

select * from @original
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the case statement as already answered is the "right way". However, you could have been a little creative. Assuming 'xxx' is never used ...

```
update table set animal = 'xxx' where animal = 'dog'
update table set animal = 'dog' where animal = 'cat'
update table set animal = 'cat' where animal = 'xxx'
```

There is more than 1 way to skin a cat.